# jquery ajax call firing both success and error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code to make an ajax request and both the success and error events are being called. This is occurring intermittently in Opera and Chrome but not IE8 (I dont have access to a higher version at the mo to check). The textStatus parameter shows error but the errorThrown parameter is emmpty. The responseHeader is null.

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/check_login.php",
        data: $(form).serialize() + "&session_key=<?php echo session_id(); ?>" + "&role=" + refer,
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(resp) { 

            if (resp == 'error') {
                $('#login_error').html('Invalid login');
            } else {

                if (refer == 'customer') {
                    self.location='book-mot.php';
                } else {
                    self.location='admin.php';
                }               
            }                               
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(request.getResponseHeader('Status'));
                    alert('text status: ' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
      return false;
    }               
});
```

The code redirects the user to the appropriate place after a successful login but it first displays the alert box from the error function.

thanks a lot for any help you can give

Comment: which version of jquery are you using? Take a look at api.jquery.com because they changed success to .done() and error to .fail() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What result are you currently receiving?

Comment: What does `check_login.php` returns? Other than that, alert the `textStatus` on `error`. Since the timeout is 3secs (`3000` is `3` secs) only, it might be triggering the error because it timed out before download of check_login response finished. If that's the case, `textStatus` on `error` will return `timeout` as value. (Other textStatus errors can be "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror").